# Proving that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{cos(x)}{x^2}dx$ is convergent/divergent?

Tags: integration

I want to determine whether $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{cos(x)}{x^2}dx$ is convergent or not. I first said that, for any $x$, $\frac{cos(x)}{x^2} \ge \frac{-10}{x^2}$. Since $\frac{-10}{x^2}$ is divergent, then the initial integral is too. However, the integral calculator website says that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{cos(x)}{x^2}dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{cos(x)}{x^2}dx$ are both convergent. Wouldn't it then follow that the initial integral is also convergent?

What error am I making? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 
$$
\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\leq \frac{-10}{x^2}
$$
for any $x$ is certainly not true, take $x=2\pi$ among many other choices.

Also, bounding something above by a divergent integral tells you nothing. Also, depending on where you are examining $1/x^2$, it can be integrable, like at infinity.

However, you were right by accident. It does not converge, and your website is wrong. 
$$
\cos(x)=1+O(x^2)
$$
so, 
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\mathrm dx\approx \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}
$$
which is not finite. So, there is no hope for $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\mathrm dx$ or $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\mathrm dx$.

Comment: My mistake, I actually meant to write $\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\geq \frac{-10}{x^2}$, hence why I chose a divergent integral. I've fixed my post. With that in mind, does my logic work? Thanks.

Comment: Still no, you have bounded it from below by $-\infty$. You want to push it off to infinity using something that diverges to *positive* infinity

Comment: Ah, of course, how dumb of me. So it's enough to say that $\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\mathrm dx\approx \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}$, because, if an integral is positively divergent within a certain interval, then it is of course divergent on any superset of that interval. Correct? Thanks again.

Comment: @user494405 that's right. Not a problem

Comment: One last question, if you don't mind. Why does $\cos(x)=1+O(x^2)$ imply that $\int_0^1\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\mathrm dx\approx \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2}$?

Comment: Sorry if that's confusing, just think of it this way: Split off a bunch of bounded things, the remaining terms in the series for $\cos x$, these will integrate to something finite, leaving you with just the first piece we already broke off. This is $+\infty$

Answer (score 1):

You might want to note that integral calculator websites can be inaccurate. I'm not saying it isn't, here, but depending on the way in the integral converges or diverges, the integral can be handled weirdly by the calculator.

Also, I will take some issue with a bit of your logic: generally speaking, for a pair of functions $f,g$ on an interval $(\alpha,\beta)$, if $|f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$, then we can say two things:

- If $\int_\alpha^\beta |g(x)|dx$ is a finite real value (what we call $g$ being "absolutely integrable" on that interval), then so is $f$
- If $\int_\alpha^\beta |f(x)|dx$ diverges, the same must be true for $g$.

Your example with $\frac{cos(x)}{x^2} \leq -\frac{10}{x^2}$ and the latter diverging doesn't mean anything in this case. (The inequality is also not true. As you can see, it implies $cos(x) \leq -10$, but $cos(x)\in [-1,1] \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.)

I'm not 100% sure how you should calculate it. My personal guess would utilizing the power series for cosine but it's just that, a guess.

Answer (score 0):

$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2}dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{-\sin(ax)}{x}dx=\pi\text{sgn}(a)$$
$$I(a)=\int\pi\text{sgn}(a)da=\pi|a|+C$$
but $C=0$ so:
$$I(a)=\pi|a|$$
which would give $I=\pi$, whilst I believe the correct answer is $I=0$ so this must be wrong somewhere